# scrapy allow all subdomains

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy to crawl a website that it's pages are divided into a lot of subdomains
I know I need a `CrawlSpider` with a `Rule` but I need the Rule to be just "allow all subdomains and let the parsers handle themselves according to the data" (meaning - in the example the item_links are in different subdomains)

example for the code:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    item_links = sel.xpath("XXXXXXXXX").extract()
    for item_link in item_links:
            item_request = Request(url=item_link,
                                     callback=self.parse_item)
            yield item_request

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
```

** EDIT **
Just to make the question clear, I want the ability to crawl all of *.example.com -> 
meaning not to get `Filtered offsite request to 'foo.example.com'`

** ANOTHER EDIT **
Following @agstudy's answer, make sure you don't forget to delete `allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set an `allow_domains` list for the  rule  :

```
rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('domain1','domain2' ), ),)
```

For example:

```
rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('example.com','example1.com' ), ),)
```

This will filter allow urls like :

```
www.example.com/blaa/bla/
www.example1.com/blaa/bla/
www.something.example.com/blaa/bla/
```

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood - I added rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('example.com'), )),
    )
and I get: Filtered offsite request to 'foo.example.com'.

Comment: yes exactly. the rule is either  exact  matching domain or the endwith domain.

Comment: so you are saying I have no option but to manually list dozens of subdomains?

Comment: maybe you should edit your question and and show some links ( at  least 3 ) to make the question more clear.

Comment: OK, got it, I had an old `allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]` before the rule that probably overrited. it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I tried with `LinkExtractor` instead of `SgmlLinkExtractor` and this worked.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using rules, but are making use of the `allowed_domains` class attribute of the Spider, you can also set `allowed_domains = ['example.com']`. That will allow all subdomains of `example.com` such as `foo.example.com`.

Comment: This works, but I was forgetting to strip the "www." from the url, which will cause issues if the recursively followed links don't specify it.